# Celery tasks not calling post_save revceiver function

Tags: django, django-celery, django-signals

I have one table 'notification', in which storing notification messages.I have written a  post_save handler function which will be called when signal raises.

I am storing data in this table by celery task, but this task is not calling this receiver function.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def send_push_notifications(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    """
    message = kwargs["instance"]
    push_notifications = MobilePushNotifications(message_object=message)
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

> Celery Task:

```
@shared_task
def send_notification(data):
   """
   """
   messages.add_row(
      user_lists,
      type,
      message,
      instance,
      extra_tags=extra_tags
  )
```

> add_row function of messages module

```
def add_row(users, type, message_text, instance, extra_tags='',fail_silently=False):
"""

"""
 for user in users:
        Notification.objects.get_or_create(user=user, message=instance)
```

Comment: Add your celery task

Comment: I guess I should have been clearer)) What `add_message_for` does? We need to see all code that executes when you are calling this task.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev, I have edited my question , please review.

Comment: signal here will be called only if `get_or_create` creates object. Are you sure that it doesn't return existing? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev, yes, creating  a new notification object for a new message every time. i have checked it.

Comment: Where is your signal receiver located? Probably it wasn't registered properly and that's why it doesn't get called

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev, I found mistake in my signal handler, now resolved. Thank you.